# How can I format my numbers so they don't show any zeroes after the decimal point?

Tags: objective-c

I have this code:

```
double result = [textField1.text doubleValue] + [textField2.text doubleValue];
answer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", result];
```

But the results show like this: `1.230000` or `1.000000`.

How can I make it so it looks like this: `1.23` or `1`?

Comment: Use `%g` instead of `%f` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change %g to %.2f and %.0f respectively.